# Почему при удлинении div content заливка обрывается?

Tags: html, css

День добрый!

В документе html имеется несколько div`ов. У сайта однотонная заливка, но почему-то, если div content удлиняется, то  заливка обрывается, не доходя до низу.

Никак не получается прижать подвал сайта к низу страницы, пробовал многие рецепты - не помогает.

Comment: А так, не: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&t=question

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style='background:#333;'>
```

Однотонная заливка. На весь сайт.
ps. Прижать подвал сайта к низу страницы? Если я правильно вас понял

```
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;'>TEEEEXT</div>
```

Comment: Фон так и задан, но сайт фиксированной ширины, а если задавать через body, то почему то на height он не реагирует, и заливает весь сайт.
Подвал фиксируется снизу и прокручивается вместе со страницей в Вашем коде, а надо, чтобы он был просто в самом низу.

Answer (score 1):

Поробуйте `vertical-align: bottom;`

Если не получится, то `margin-bottom: -X;`

Comment: Увы, но ни то, ни другое не сработало.

Comment: @bumial - страница в сети? если да - ссылку, если нет - выложите код

Comment: Если вам весь код, то он весьма не маленький.

Comment: @bumial люди с хэшкода большого кода не боятся. так что выкладывайте

Comment: Если Вам весь код сайта, то он не подходит по кол-ву символов.

Comment: @bumial, есть сервис [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), выложите туда. Сюда же ссылку на результат

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qKQ5F/1/
Работает только в хроме и подобных. Почему в остальных не работает не знаю, если всё совсем плохо, то скажите, первый раз:)

Answer (score 1):

Для прижатия подвала книзу экрана вы задаете для html и body height:100%. Поэтому когда контента больше, чем 100% они и не "удлиняются". А главному контейнеру вы задаете min-height: 100%. Вот для него и надо задать фоновый цвет.)

Comment: Да, вроде бы сделал min и цвет главному контейнеру, а всё равно обрезается как заканчивается экран. То ли код кривоват, то ли что? Про подвал решил, что он будет частью контета, только будет находиться ниже него.

Comment: Выложите куда-нибудь код. Без него трудно что-то сказать